# find out which page event has bound

Tags: jquery, events

is there a way to track an event, on which page it was assign from?

e.g.

**mypage.js**

```
$(function(){
   $('selector').click(function (){
//      blabla
   })
})
```

What I need is when I click somewhere I can track it which page it was binded from jquery.

My problem is that I don't know on which page the event is bound or searching for it is proving difficult I was wondering that when I do click on something to track what happened where. like php backtracking.

Comment: It can only be bound from the CURRENT page.

Comment: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables/demo_events.html giving this a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass window.location to the monitoring script, ie:

```
$(function(){
   $('selector').click(function (){
    $.get('monit.php?location='+window.location);
   })
})
```

You can also add location.hash if you are using hashes:

```
$(function(){
   $('selector').click(function (){
    $.get('monit.php?location='+window.location+'#'+location.hash);
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the URL in a cookie and read the cookie on subsequent pages.